# Phong implementation seems dark and also specular not working. Ray tracing

Tags: c++, raytracing, phong

Below is my phong implementation method where I am drawing a sphere.  Its parameters are vec3 sphere normal (which is my vec3 hitpoint - vec3 sphereOrigin) and the camera position vec3 (0,0,-5).

Using couts I find that the dot product in my specular calculation is returning ~ -4.9xxx, so 0 always wins in the max function it is contained in, and also makes the rest of the line redundant because it's 0.  Is there something wrong with this method?

Also it seems very dark,  I crank up my light intensity to (5,5,5) for a nicer sphere.

```
vec3 implementPhong(vec3 normal, vec3 camera){
    vec3 lightSource1(0,0,-1); 
    vec3 nLightSource1 = normalize(lightSource1);
    float zero = 0;

    //Material properties brass
    vec3 ambient(0.329412, 0.223529, 0.027451);
    vec3 diffuse_albedo = vec3(0.780392, 0.568627, 0.113725);
    vec3 specular_albedo = vec3(0.992157,0.941176,0.807843);
    float specular_power = 27.8974;
    vec3 light_intensity = vec3(1,1,1);

    vec3 realLight = light_intensity * nLightSource1;

    vec3 reflection = reflect(-realLight, normal);

    vec3 diffuse = std::max<float>(dot(normal, realLight), zero) * diffuse_albedo;

    vec3 specular = pow(std::max<float>(dot(reflection, camera), zero), specular_power) * specular_albedo;

    vec3 color = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    return color;
}
```

Current image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6IK5.jpg  Phong only attempted on the front sphere atm.

Comment: Can you post an image?

Comment: Your specular power should be much higher 128 e.g.  and is your camera normalized as well?

Comment: The Camera and sphere normal that are passed in are both normalized.  I don't have to normalize the specular power do I?  Or light intensity?

Comment: Added image for you.

Comment: No not the lightinsentiy or specular power, they are just multipliers. Is you camera, normal in view-space?